# Unable to manage my chef server using UI

Tags: nginx, chef-infra

I want to manage my chef server using UI

```
https://EIP of chef server
```

Error

```
502 Bad Gateway
nginx/1.2.3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [chef-server-ctl status](http://docs.opscode.com/ctl_chef_server.html) to observe the status of the services or have a look at `/var/log/chef/server.log`.

Comment: i edit my /etc/hosts then i can able to manage using UI